# Looking for sample of nsITreeView implementation in C++

Tags: treeview, xul, xpcom, xulrunner

i am searching for a sample of c++ implementation of nsITreeView interface.
Files from Mozilla source code give no help.
Can someone help me to find such sample?

I need to make custom treeview in c++.
Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

There is for example [nsFileView](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/a5e63e00db27/toolkit/components/filepicker/nsFileView.cpp#l294) displaying a files tree for the file picker. That should be one of the simpler implementations.

Comment: Great thanx, Wladimir, i spent much time trying to compile nsTreeContentView.cpp and nsXULTreeBuilder.cpp from source code, but without success. I think i can build this nsFileView XPCOM component and then make my own component out of it.

Comment: I believed that you personaly could help me. I was almost desperate))

Comment: i compiled nsFileView.cpp, no errors,
but can not build library. There are many unresolved external refs.
It looks like VS 2010 do not see "lib" folder from xulrunner-sdk which i set in project parameters. Could you help me once more?